# How can I keep the native values of slider's background and fill image?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the native sizes of sprites to modify my slider. I set the native sizes but when I modify the value of the slider, fill image's width, height & position completely changes. I think slider controls the values of the fill image. How can I fix this ?

Comment: A picture would be of great help.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean but here my guess: You mean if you change the "slider" value the Sprite gets stretched? Have  a look at the Image component, there is the [`type`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image-type.html) property (in the Inspector it's called `Image Type`). You would want to use "Filled" since in the API it says `As a partial image, useful for wipes, fades, timers, status bars etc.`. Also have a look at the [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-image)

Answer (score 0):

I just created 2 different game objects with `Image` components. For the bar itself I set `Image`s type to`Fill`and adjusted the value via script by  `imageName.fillAmount`.

Answer (score 0):

My First Reply in Stack Over Flow
When you put the image in Fill image component
then press Native size button and after resize it the way you want it
when you are done set anchors to strech
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Wsi.png)